# JQuery Smart Wizard onFinish not working

Tags: jquery, html, smart-wizard

I have this code of the form wizard.

```
<div id="wizard" class="form_wizard wizard_horizontal">
   <ul class="wizard_steps">
      <!-- the <li> -->
   </ul>
   <div id="step-1">
   </div>
   <div id="step-2">
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I have this code. The problem is that whenever I click the finish button, the function is not being triggered. The alert doesn't show up. Is there a problem in my code?

```
$('#wizard').smartWizard({
    onFinish:onFinishCallback
});
function onFinishCallback(){
    alert("Finished");
}
```

Comment: what is `smart wizard`?

Comment: I think what he means is https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard